# Single Sign-on using ReactJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, single-sign-on

I have to integrate Single Sign-on in existing project. I have basic knowledge of how SSO works.

**What I have already in my existing project is -**

- UI created in ReactJS.
- APIs are in Express with PostgreSQL database.
- Both are hosted on different server and communicate using APIs only.

**What's going in the project -**

- Registration with more than ten custom fields
- Login and Logout.

**My need -**

- Implement Single Sign-on functionality

**My questions -**

- Name of few Single Sign-on providers?
- Where custom registration fields will be saved and how?
- Which logic implement in ReactJS and Express?

Comment: Previously I have created the same app using Hapi and AngularJS. I have used jwt2 authentication and it was working like a charm! But for now I need authentication on different server. One more thing, I also need to check user type.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score -3):

try json web token.

https://jwt.io/introduction/

and there are so many jwt tutorials you can google them.